# Error after rails migration 4.2.6 to 5.1.0

Tags: ruby, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have migrated one of my rails project from 4.2.5 to 5.1.0

I follow this tutorial for migration: https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/how-to-upgrade-to-rails-5

After migration when I run rails db:migrate I found following error.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `wrappers' for SimpleForm:Module Did you mean?  wrapper_class
```

Please note I don't use any gem like SimpleForm in my project.

My ruby version is: 2.4.1

Comment: Hi @Sirajus can you let me know what you get when you do `cat Gemfile.lock | grep simpleform` or `cat Gemfile.lock | grep simple` ?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its related to client_side_validation gem compatibility.

https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap/issues/4

go through this for more info

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are running old version of simple_form try upgrading it to the latest version. which should work with rails 5. if you are specifying a version in your Gemfile remove the version tag, and run `bundle update`